# Using frequency table in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to organize some data to obtain the absolute frequency, in the amplitude I do not divide by the Storges law, but rather divided by the ceiling of the root of the data.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.array(
  [[0.424,0.879,0.927,0.993,0.340,0.633,0.363,0.700,0.828,0.787],
  [0.117,0.147,0.093,0.502,0.247,0.993,0.465,0.595,0.509,0.344],
  [0.565,0.294,0.933,0.950,0.944,0.936,0.448,0.821,0.461,0.599],
  [0.585,0.693,0.731,0.935,0.578,0.232,0.462,0.001,0.309,0.319],
  [0.577,0.531,0.642,0.534,0.707,0.120,0.740,0.648,0.238,0.002],
  [0.010,0.688,0.286,0.512,0.655,0.452,0.025,0.699,0.555,0.072],
  [0.981,0.113,0.500,0.811,0.843,0.924,0.144,0.057,0.008,0.250],
  [0.053,0.531,0.596,0.299,0.726,0.569,0.677,0.726,0.785,0.844],
  [0.164,0.714,0.044,0.077,0.602,0.262,0.053,0.023,0.482,0.418],
  [0.505,0.052,0.850,0.680,0.550,0.287,0.378,0.177,0.820,0.528]]
)
```

```
datos = data.flatten()
clases = math.ceil(math.sqrt(len(datos)))
amplitud = (datos.max() - datos.min()) / clases
inf = datos.min()
#dif = (datos.max() - datos.min()) % amplitud # If I add this to Sup, then I get all 100 data, but Amplitude is damaged
sup = datos.max()

intervals = pd.interval_range(
  start=inf,
  end=sup,
  freq=amplitud,
  name="intervalo",
  closed="left",
)

df = pd.DataFrame(index=intervals)
df["Freq_Abs"] = pd.cut(datos, bins=df.index).value_counts()
df["Marca"]  = df.index.mid
```

and this prints

```
                               Freq_Abs Marca
intervalo
[0.001, 0.1002)                     14  0.0506
[0.1002, 0.1994)                     7  0.1498
[0.1994, 0.2986)                     8  0.2490
[0.2986, 0.3978)                     7  0.3482
[0.3978, 0.497)                      8  0.4474
[0.497, 0.5962)                     18  0.5466
[0.5962, 0.6954)                    10  0.6458
[0.6954, 0.7946)                    10  0.7450
[0.7946, 0.8937999999999999)         8  0.8442
[0.8937999999999999, 0.993)          8  0.9434
```

But I am missing two data, if you can see the column absolute frequency (`Freq_Abs`) I get 98 data, and it is really 100 data. How could you correct this without affecting the width of the intervals? And then how could you get this absolute frequency as an array?

I appreciate any help or documentation.

Comment: cant help thinking it something to do with the interval. If you use the default `closed=right` then do `df["Freq_Abs"].sum()` you get `99`.

Comment: I have done something less than optimal but that works for these intervals, add 0.0001 to the width of the interval so that it takes the elements that it ignores in the extreme right of the interval, like this: `amplitud = ((datos.max() - datos.min()) / clases) + 0.0001 ` after `dif = (datos.min() - datos.max()) % amplitud` and I rest it to the upper limits `sup = datos.max() + dif`